# How to access accountUserLinks in the Google Analtyics managment api with python?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, google-remarketing-audience

I'm looking for the library for this method
analytics.management().accountUserLinks().insert

everytime I try to run it the error is always the same, the method management() doesn't exists into the analytics library.
I've got this from the documentation so I think it should works.

I've tried to download different python libraries without success.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Google analytics management api.  Is part of the Google apis library.

Which means you can use the google-api-python-client

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

## sample

```
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

import argparse

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users.readonly']

# Service account key file
CREDENTIALS = 'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json'

VIEW_ID = '78110423'

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, client_secrets_path):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: string The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: string The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list of strings representing the auth scopes to authorize for the
      connection.
    client_secrets_path: string A path to a valid client secrets file.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      client_secrets_path, scope=scope,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secrets_path))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage(api_name + '.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for the authorized user.
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    account_links = service.management().accountUserLinks().list(
        accountId=account
    ).execute()

    if account_links.get('items', []):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return account_links.get('items', [])

  return None

def print_results(results):
    print(results)


def main():

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', SCOPES, CREDENTIALS)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(profile)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```